# RAILS - ActiveAdmin disable comments delete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, activeadmin

After integrating the `ActiveAdmin` panel, I tried to find where can I modifiy any options to remove the possibility to `delete comments`

But I can't find this anywhere

it is possible the remove the `comments` removal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can do it providing your own AuthorizationAdapter as described here: http://activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html

Your `authorized?` method should be:

```
  def authorized?(action, subject = nil)
    !(action == ActiveAdmin::Auth::DESTROY && subject.is_a?(ActiveAdmin::Comment))
  end
```

**Solution 2**

Or you can override ActiveAdmin's `build_comment` method which generates comment partials.

Put this into `lib/active_admin.rb`

```
# Overriding ActiveAdmin's `build_comment` method.
# The original code is here: 
# https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/d01155f73a0e2cc27d712792270357e2b3759d05/lib/active_admin/orm/active_record/comments/views/active_admin_comments.rb
#
module ActiveAdmin
  module Comments
    module Views
      class Comments < ActiveAdmin::Views::Panel
        def build_comment(comment)
          div for: comment do
            div class: 'active_admin_comment_meta' do
              h4 class: 'active_admin_comment_author' do
                comment.author ? auto_link(comment.author) : I18n.t('active_admin.comments.author_missing')
              end
              span pretty_format comment.created_at
            end
            div class: 'active_admin_comment_body' do
              simple_format comment.body
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The first solution is better.